# How to restream an udp live stream using nginx rtmp module?

Tags: nginx, stream, udp, streaming, rtmp

I need to restream a live stream which is in UDP protocol using nginx RTMP module. So the final stream will be in RTMP protocol. I have tried the command below in the configuration file of nginx(inside the RTMP server)

```
exec_pull ffmpeg -re -i udp://ipaddress:portnumber -f flv rtmp://localhost/$appname/$streamname;
```

When I am writing the rtmp stream link in VLC I am not able to get any display. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Try to execute the `ffmpeg -i udp://...` command in the terminal (using the actual app/stream name) and see if you have any errors.

Comment: @aergistal I have tried but I can not get any display. I wrote ffmpeg -i udp://...  -f flv rtmp://localhost/$appname/$streamname in the command line

Comment: replace $appname and $streamname with the actual values in the test command

Comment: @aergistal From the beginning they are the actual ones, I wrote in that way just for showing you. It is interesting that I don't get any errror in the command line but I can not get any display.

Comment: But does it do something or it just hangs? Also, are you able to play the source stream with `ffplay udp://ipaddress:portnumber`?

Comment: It just hangs. The black screen. Is not opening the display. I am sure that ffmpeg is workign since I have checked it with a video on deman application. I tried it now. The response in the end is as shown below: nan: 0.000 fd= 0 aq= 0KB vq=0KB sq=0B f=0/0 @aergistal

Comment: It seems your source stream (UDP) is not available.

Comment: I don't think so. Since it is a stream which is broadcasted on the IP TV platform. If it is possible can you guide me from the beginning how should I restream an udp stream as rtmp. Because I think somewhere I am making a small mistake. By the way the application name is the name defined in the nginx configuration file. Could there be any problem that is causing these much trouble to me? @aergistal