# re-stream other stream with niginx software

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, stream

Goodday everybody,
I have question about Nginx streaming software and the resteaming from other streams.
I wanne restream another stream (third party) with nginx because this way I wanne create so called thumbs from the (third party) stream and stream it on my own site .
The thumbs part is what I all know , the part of the restream is the unkown part for me .
Long story short now .
1. The stream link what I like restream is

> http://154.57.145.83/flv/5285079c2c9e5/testat123.flv

As out going stream on my site I wanne have it like :

> rtmp://145.44.194.308:1935/myapp/flv:test.flv

I have found this like on stackoverflow as well but it haven't help me out so far . ([How to restream an udp live stream using nginx rtmp module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29515430/how-to-restream-an-udp-live-stream-using-nginx-rtmp-module))

This is my code what I have used and dont seems to work .

> exec_pull ffmpeg -i
>   http://154.57.145.83/flv/5285079c2c9e5/testat123.flv -c:v libx264 -c:a
>   libfaac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://145.44.194.308:1935/myapp/test;

So I hope someone here can help me out because I think other people will like to do same thing as well

Greatings and have yourself an great day

Answer (score 0):

I have found the anwers for someone that wanne use it as well

> exec_pull ffmpeg -re -i
>   http://154.57.145.83/flv/5285079c2c9e5/testat123.flv -c:a libmp3lame
>   -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://415.493.196.188:1935/myapp/test 2>>/tmp/log/ffmpeg.log;